# Variable in sas for endpoints

Tags: sas

if I have something like

```
proc univariate data=work.testDateSet noprint;
histogram value/ midpoints=(-2.45 to 2.45 by .05) outhist=newDataSet;
run;

data work.test;

set work.testDataSet;

Char_1=put(_midpt _-0.05,4.2);

Char_2=put(_midpt _+0.05,4.2);

run;
```

in sas is there a variable for endpoints If I change midpoints to endpoints can I still extract the endpoints by doing something like _endpt _ .

Answer (score 0):

You get a variable called `_MINPT_`, which is the leftmost endpoint.  The rightmost endpoint would be any value less than the next `_MINPT_` value.  You can access this via a side by side merge (note: if `MERGENOBY=ERROR` is in effect for your site, this won't work.)

Example:

```
proc univariate data=sashelp.class noprint;
histogram age/ endpoints=(11 to 16 by 1) outhist=newDataSet;
run;

data work.test;
merge work.newdataset work.newdataset(firstobs=2 keep=_MINPT_ rename=_MINPT_=_MAXPT_);
if missing(_MAXPT_) then _MAXPT_=99999;
run;
```